# How to pass different types of property values using reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, reflection

Using reflection, I am populating a combobox with class types, then creating textboxes for input, based on each classes public properties.

Considering that each class has properties that return different types (string, float, int), how can I validate each type, pass them from the textbox to create class instances that are passed to a listbox ? Each textbox has to take different types.

The main goal is to send these instances to the listbox.
I am learning reflection and linq, so I want to do this using them.

I tried using this Dictionary, but I can't use it to treat more than one property type.

```
    private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> populatedProperties = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                                              .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => ValidateInputType(x.Text));

        User createdUser = (User)Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in selectedType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite))
        {
            property.SetValue(createdUser, populatedProperties[property.Name]);
        }

        listBoxUsers.Items.Add(createdUser.ToString());
    }
```

//I am creating textboxes using:
            int i = 50;

```
        foreach (var prop in selectedUserType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite))
        {
            Controls.Add( new TextBox
            {
                Name = prop.Name,
                Location = new Point(150, 10 + i),
                Tag = prop
            });

            i = i + 40;
        }
```

//And validating:

```
    private string ValidateInputType(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return "Input is null or White Space";
    }
```

I expect to to able to pass these various properties to the listBox.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your foreach loop when you create your textbox add a text validation on text change and point directly to the validator of that textbox.

While you are inside the foreach loop you could get the property type which you could use to point the ontextchange event of the specific text box to the correct validator.

Just so you know its 
OnTextChanged